# Tabulator - Getting Columns including order and size

Tags: tabulator

I am creating a table using Tabulator, which seems great and very powerful.

I want a way to save relevant data of the table so it can e recreated on the fly.

Currently, I think there are a few things I need...

1. The row data - I get this using table.getData();
2. The columns - I get this using table.getColumnDefinitions();

The row data seems perfect I can store that and use it. However, the column information I am saving doesnt appear to have the size of the columns if I have resized them?

Is there a way of getting ALL the relevant column info, so I can save and recreate it exactly?

Alternatively, if there's a single 1 function that saves everything (row data, columns (including order, size etc)) in one go as a JSON or something that may be handy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a few options here.

#### Config Persistence

If you simply want the table to be the same way it was the last time the user used it on that computer, you could look at using the [Peristent Configuration](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.9/persist) module. This will store a copy of the table column configuration on the browsers local storage so that next time they load the page it will be laid out the same.

#### Column Layout

If you want to store it externally then you are correct,
the column width is not updated in the definition after a user changes it.

If you want to get the current layout of the columns then you can use the `getColumnLayout` function to retrieve the current layout of columns:

```js
var columnLayout = table.getColumnLayout();
```

Though this will only contain the key layout characteristics and not the full definition, you would need to merge them if you wanted to store them in one place.

More details on this method can be found in the [Manual Column Layout Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.9/persist#manual-columns)

Comment: Thanks. Perhaps one for your enhancement list to make this easier? I haven't tried it yet but marked as accepted.

Comment: It is actually done this way for very good reason. most developers don't want to store the whole updated column layout. they want to be able to specify the columns themselves in code so that when they make structural changes these are reflected in the table, and then only store the user changed options such as order, visibility and width. that is how the built in persistence system works, the `getColumnLayout` function and the matching `setColumnLayout` function then ley you handle the storing and retrieval of this styling information without affecting the underlying table structure